# Ajax loading GIF not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gif

I have a HTML form that calls a JS function to validate fields. This JS function returns false if there are any errors, otherwise returns true and adds a loading GIF to a proper DIV.

The problem is the loading GIF never appears in the browser. It just shows a blank space. The GIF path is correct. It only works if my validation function returns false instead of true after the loading GIF is added.

Here is an example of how my code looks like :

```
function validate()
{
  if (document.getElementById('email').value === '')
  {
    alert('Please enter your email');
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#loading_div').html('<img src="images/info-loading.gif" />');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Actual function is more complex, but the logic is just like this above.

Thanks !

Comment: That is because the form action is executing and a new page is loading

Comment: Are any JS errors shown on the console? You are missing an apostrophe from `$('#loading_div)` too.

Comment: if ((document.getElementById('email')).value === '')

Comment: Did you try to use the append function inside the div, instead of the .html to add the image?

Comment: Please correct your code from script error.

Comment: I corrected some syntax errors, check if it works now, there shouldn't be any errors anymore.

Comment: Try this `var img='<img src="images/info-loading.gif">';

$("#loading_div").html(img);`

Comment: The actual script has no errors, i just typed it incorrectly. The code works, no errors are shown in the console. Just my GIF does not appear.

Comment: Keep corrections to your coding style, don't revert them. There are specific rules that should be respected in FOSS and on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can depend on when the validate is called - if it is before the `$('#loading_div')` has fully loaded then it won't work.

While AJAX calls are asynchronous things like DOM renders are not - what are you trying to do while the loading gif should be displayed?

From the comments you said this is how it's being called:

```
<input type="Submit" id="Login" value="Login" onclick="return validate();">
```

This code means that when `validate()` returns false the button does nothing, when it returns true the submit button goes on and does its default behaviour - i.e. it submits the form. Once form submission has started the page is going to be unloaded, and so doesn't load any further resources.

What you could try is loading the spinner first, something like:

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('email').value === '') {
        alert('Please enter your email');
        return false;
    }  else {
        // Set the loading image
        $('#loading_div').html('<img src="images/info-loading.gif"/>');

        // Submit the form 200ms later
        var $form = $(this).parents('form');
        window.setTimeout(function() {$form.submit();}, 200);

        // Return false so that the form post back doesn't start right away.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually #loading_div is an empty div, i use it only to show the append the code to show the loading GIF.

Comment: @delphirules that's not quite what I mean - has the DOM content loaded? Assuming that it has - what context are you firing `validate()`? Page load? DOM content complete? Before a `$.ajax` call?

Comment: Yes, the page is completety loaded ; i call validate() when the user clicks a Login button, just like this : <input type="Submit" id="Login" value="Login" onclick="return validate();">

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error. it showing in your question highlight. you did not close selector quotation.  you also have extra `)`.

replace this:

```
   function validate {
    if (document.getElementById('email')).value === '') {
      alert('Please enter your email');
      return false;
    }  else {
    $('#loading_div).html('<img src="images/info-loading.gif">');
    return true;
    }
}
```

by:

```
   function validate {
    if (document.getElementById('email').value === '') {
      alert('Please enter your email');
      return false;
    }  else {

    $('#loading_div').html('<img src="images/info-loading.gif">');
        return true;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you but the actual code has no errors, i just typed incorrectly in the question

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error.

```
 function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('email').value === '') {
          alert('Please enter your email');
          return false;
        }  else {
        $('#loading_div').html('<img src="images/info-loading.gif"/>');
        return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but the actual code has no errors, i just typed incorrectly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding  to the page to test the file path works?

Also, good practice to close your elements. Add a closing slash.

Comment: Yes, the path is correct ; if i return FALSE in my validation function after adding the GIF, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a `)` parens too much?

```
if (document.getElementById('email')).value === '') {
                                    ^ what is this?
```

There were many more syntax errors I corrected by re-editing your code. Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you but the actual code has no errors, i just typed incorrectly in the question

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to have the loading gif in the div from the beginning, but have styled with `display: none;`, and show/hide it with [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Cool approach, but in this case i would pre-load an image that i don't really know if will be necessary ; the user could cancel the operation, for instance.